# Stop audioclip from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to stop an audioclip that will be played from an empty `gameobject` that has a script attached to it.

The attached script will play the music and another script attached to another `gameobject` will be stop it.

How can I accomplish this?

I could use an audiosource instead, but if I did, how could I invoke `audio.stop()` from the second script attached to the second `gameobject`?

Answer (score 1):

All you'll need to do is access the script in GameObject A from GameObject B, and call a method to stop playing the clip.

Example

***Attach AudioPlayer.cs to GameObject A***

```
public class AudioPlayer : Monobehaviour {

    public static AudioSource instance;
    private AudioSource audioSource;

    void Awake () {
        instance = this;
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    public void PlayClip () {
        //Assumption is that you've assigned the audio clip to this source in the inspector
        audioSource.Play();
    }

    public void StopClip () {
        audioSource.Stop();
    }

}
```

***Attach AudioController.cs to GameObject B***

```
public class AudioController : Monobehaviour {

    void OnGUI () {
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 150, 50), "Play Clip"))
            AudioPlayer.instance.PlayClip();

         if(GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 70, 150, 50), "Stop Clip"))
            AudioPlayer.instance.StopClip();
    }
}
```